# Multiple reuseIdentifiers - UITableView Cells of Differing Heights

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview

I've gotten different perspectives on this from different sources, and I'd like to clear it up. When calling `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`, a required method, can I dynamically resize cell heights depending on the data within them? Can this be done 'on the fly' or do I need to standardize five or six prototype cells and choose which cell to use based on its `reuseIdentifier`.

If for example I called

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  return [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]*20;
}
```

would this draw all necessary cells immediately, and then still be swapping out these same cells or would it redraw the cells once they leave the screen. Why would I need to have multiple prototype cells?

Answer (score 1):

Answer: yes - yes, it can be done "one the fly" as you put it. Yes you can give every cell a different height using that method, even if the cells have the same reuse identifier. I typically use different reuse identifiers for cells if I'm going to display different things, with different cells.

BTW, heightForRowAtIndexPath is not a required method - it's only necessary if you have cells of different heights (as you want to do).

BTW2: heightForRowAtIndexPath will be called for every index path before the cell is rendered, so the table view can compute the total height of the content.

BTW3: your implementation of heightForRow... is weird: First of all, indexPathForSelectedRow returns an indexPath, which is not a scalar (and thus you can't * 20 it) - this shouldn't compile, actually. Second of all, that would give every cell the same height, if it even worked.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 8 you can use auto layout to adopt to different heights. [This is covered in this answer very nicely.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights)

Under iOS 7 and earlier this is not possible with auto layout. UIKit uses a two step process to render a table view:

1. Gather the height of all cells in the table view
2. Get UITableViewCell objects when they need to be displayed

The height must be returned by `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`.

This delegate method is called every time for each cell as Apple states in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:):

> Every time a table view is displayed, it calls
>   tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: on the delegate for each of its
>   rows, which can result in a significant performance problem with table
>   views having a large number of rows (approximately 1000 or more).

To speed things up `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` was introduced by iOS 7 to give an approximation of the height.

> **Can I dynamically resize cell heights depending on the data within
>   them?**

Yes, you can, but you have to do it within `heightForRowAtIndexPath`. You cannot change the height dynamically from within `- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;`